# How to reduce the time of the "networking.service" service?

Tags: debian, systemd, network-interface, networkmanager, interface

I have been using linux for some time and I have already learned to adapt to this new operating system so I want to improve some details of my configuration.

Currently the system loads fast, but I see that it stops in seven parts. Analyzing with the command `systemd-analyze blame` ob I have the following information:

```
diego@computer:~$ systemd-analyze blame
    1min 13.120s networking.service
         11.960s postgresql@11-main.service
          9.792s mariadb.service
          7.845s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          7.706s ifupdown-pre.service
          6.190s udisks2.service
          5.742s apache2.service
          5.220s ModemManager.service
          4.989s NetworkManager.service
          4.746s dev-sda6.device
          4.457s accounts-daemon.service
          3.785s bluetooth.service
          3.715s avahi-daemon.service
          3.710s wpa_supplicant.service
          3.709s sysstat.service
          3.702s alsa-restore.service
          3.700s rsyslog.service
          3.697s systemd-logind.service
          3.694s pppd-dns.service
          3.168s teamviewerd.service
          2.685s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7add5e56\x2dd7d9\x2d4870\x2d9edf\x2d653b241363d3.service
          2.208s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-653a5644\x2d63e1\x2d4258\x2dbbb5\x2de1f1c1d2cd2f.service
          2.131s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-AAF1\x2dAC6F.service
          1.142s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3f7a45e2\x2d6e0b\x2d4d72\x2d9e97\x2df87224e624ba.service
           861ms boot-efi.mount
           744ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
           738ms systemd-udevd.service
           717ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
           712ms apparmor.service
           678ms polkit.service
           644ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
           613ms upower.service
           573ms systemd-rfkill.service
           497ms keyboard-setup.service
           444ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
           432ms systemd-random-seed.service
           334ms home.mount
           295ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           294ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           287ms systemd-sysctl.service
           282ms sddm.service
           264ms systemd-journald.service
           249ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           208ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8c3c1e52\x2de46b\x2d496e\x2d9432\x2dc939674ae532.swap
           195ms user@1000.service
           192ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           187ms phpsessionclean.service
           184ms systemd-sysusers.service
           181ms var.mount
           155ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           139ms plymouth-read-write.service
           112ms console-setup.service
            95ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            94ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
            90ms plymouth-quit.service
            72ms tmp.mount
            66ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            57ms packagekit.service
            57ms rtkit-daemon.service
            55ms systemd-user-sessions.service
            55ms systemd-modules-load.service
            44ms dev-mqueue.mount
            41ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
            33ms dev-hugepages.mount
            28ms plymouth-start.service
            23ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
            21ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
            17ms postgresql.service
            95ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            94ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
            90ms plymouth-quit.service
            72ms tmp.mount
            66ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            57ms packagekit.service
            57ms rtkit-daemon.service
            55ms systemd-user-sessions.service
            55ms systemd-modules-load.service
            44ms dev-mqueue.mount
            41ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
            33ms dev-hugepages.mount
            28ms plymouth-start.service
            23ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
            21ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
```

As far as I can understand, the "networking.service" service is the one that consumes the most time and, according to what is indicated in this [link](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html), is associated with the "lo" interface of my laptop.

**My query is how I can improve the configuration of this service since from what I understand the interface "lo" is the one associated to my own laptop internally.**

*OBS: My laptop used "Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"*

**UPDATE - detail of "cat /etc/network/interfaces"**

```
diego@computer:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Please include the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` in your question.

Comment: I add the dateil of "/etc/network/interfaces" in the question @Ferenc Wágner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably see the DHCP timeout on enp2s0. Since you use NetworkManager anyway, I suggest that you simply remove the enp2s0 interface definition from `/etc/network/interfaces`, trusting enp2s0 to NetworkManager.